# JMSSerializerBundle and Propel without editing the base models generated

Tags: php, symfony, propel, jmsserializerbundle

I'm developing a Symfony application and I want to use `JMSSerializerBundle` to deserialize XML into a Propel model.

Is this possible without editing the base models generated?